# Fetch data at a given specific time?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I am creaiting a leaderboard for my game using unity + firebase realtime database. How can I determine the winner of the week at a given speific time to announce it to players?
For example, every Sunday 00:00, how can I fetch the leader?

Thanks in advance,
Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

You can implement android alarm manager by writing it in Java and use JNI to call the Java method.

> Alarms (based on the AlarmManager class) give you a way to perform
>   time-based operations outside the lifetime of your application. For
>   example, you could use an alarm to initiate a long-running operation,
>   such as starting a service once a day to download a weather forecast.
>
> Alarms have these characteristics:
>
> They let you fire Intents at set times and/or intervals. You can use
>   them in conjunction with broadcast receivers to start services and
>   perform other operations. They operate outside of your application, so
>   you can use them to trigger events or actions even when your app is
>   not running, and even if the device itself is asleep. They help you to
>   minimize your app's resource requirements. You can schedule operations
>   without relying on timers or continuously running background services.

https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will check it!